# Establish SSO and session sharing between two webapplications running on Tomcat 6

Tags: jsf, struts, tomcat6, single-sign-on

I have two web applications, webapp1 (JSF-Spring) and webapp2 (Struts) running on a single Tomcat 6.0.  Webapp1 uses JSF phase listener to protect all the resources within the webapp.
After user is authenticated to webapp1, it renders a page from which webapp2 is invoked via an `<iframe>` tag.

My questions are:

1. How can SSO be established between webapp1 and webapp2?
2. How can session be shared between webapp1 and webapp2?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace the `PhaseListener` by a `Filter` which does basically the same job and use it on both webapps. This assumes that session is shared and that you've put the logged-in user in the session.
2. Set `emptySessionPath` attribute of the [`<Context>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) element of both webapps to `true`.

   ```
   <Context emptySessionPath="true">
   ```

   This can be provided by a `/META-INF/context.xml` file. See also the linked documentation.